# Get Class name from within a method

Tags: java, junit

I would like to reference a Class's name within a method.  In the following example, I would like TestSuite to be printed out.  I can put `CarsTestSuite.class.getName()`, but I'd like to use the method to get the class name so that I never have to edit it.  The solution will find the method's class instead of myself filling it in.

```
public class TestSuite extends TestCase {

    public static void testOne() {
        System.out.println(<want TestSuite to be here>);
```

Answer (score 6):

`this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` or `this.getClass().getName()`.

Your method is static so this won't work.  Does it need to be static?

Comment: No it doesn't need to be static and the above example: this.getClass().getName() worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a static method.  In a non-static method you can call `getClass()`, but in a static method the method's class never changes, and thus the class (and thus its name) can only be accessed statically, and in `TestSuite.class`.

Answer (score 0):

I do need it to be static because in another class I call that class.  So if I do

TestSuite.testOne();

in another class, it will not let me do so unless I have testOne() declared as static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the stacktrace of exception consists information about current class and method in first element. I used such construct when I wanted to log current class name:

```
new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName()
```

In the same way you can retrieve also current method name (`StackTraceElement.getMethodName()`)